# rdlc report in pdf is not displaying in center

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one `.rdlc` report and rendered it in a web page using microsoft's `ReportViewer` control.

This report contains one table to display records. When I export this report to **PDF**, the table in pdf is left aligned (while on webpage,it was center aligned).

Is there any settings for the table to display it in center in **pdf**? Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: not sure if it helps, but [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127866/how-to-center-the-report-title-in-rdlc-file).

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience of using Rotativa to produce PDFs, I was had to style every field that was included in the PDF view. What I did to align my fields to right and left was:

```
<div style="float:right; padding-right:150px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseNo, "HouseNo")</b>
        <span style="padding-left:60px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HouseNo)
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try wrapping a div around your table with the float and padding attributes to centre it.

Comment: Richa I found these http://forums.asp.net/t/1562172.aspx?how+to+display+the+rdlc+report+Center+aligned+in+reportviewer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f6a3642b-6a72-4718-ab01-edb29c26c56f/re-rdlc-file-preview-in-webapp-and-pdf-view-doesnt-match-in-sql-server-2008-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/767067/RDLC-Report-Grouping-with-Page-Break-Table-Header they might help

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127866/how-to-center-the-report-title-in-rdlc-file?lq=1